# How to use SDF with ROS packages in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, clearpath, sdf, xacro, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

I have created a model for a robot that is similar to Clearpath's Jackal. What I am trying to do is have the already-created Jackal packages apply to my robot model. In other words, I am trying to substitute the model of Clearpath's Jackal with my robot model so that Clearpath's Jackal packages can apply to my model.

The robot I made is in SDF while the packages for Clearpath's jackal reference and use URDF/XACRO.  Does anyone know if it is possible to implement the SDF files and/or remove the URDF/XACRO files from the packages so that the Clearpath's Jackal's packages would apply to my model? If it is possible, what would be the best implementation process?

Thanks!

Pooja

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238183/how-to-use-sdf-with-ros-packages-in-gazebo?/) by [poojamool](https://answers.ros.org/users/27306/poojamool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2016-11-15**:
Hey! did you get it? I am having a similar problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the title line you mentioned "in Gazebo" but in the body I got the impression that you're willing to operate a real robot using SDF. If I'm so please update the title.

Anyways, based on my assumption above, AFAIK you can't / will be very limited to operate your ROS-based robot with SDF. See #q204803.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0